# PictureBox changes to opposite of what I want

Tags: c#

So I'm working on a quarter 2 project for my programming class, and I'm making a game in Visual Studio. I know, it may not be ideal for games, but I don't really have the time to move all my work onto Unity. So my problem, is that I have code set up so that when you press space, if the player (all this I'm doing with pictures and GIFs btw) is facing right, he'll swing his sword right, and if he's left, he'll swing left. There's a timer that, when done, changes the player anim back to idle. I test it, and when he's facing left and I press space, he swings left and ends left. The problem is, he does the same thing while facing right. I've tried everything I know, and the teacher is too busy helping everyone else to completely study my coding. Can anyone please help me out here?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Sprite_The_Knight
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Title;
        titleLabel.Show();
        startLabel.Show();
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightIdle;
    }

    private void EnemiesReady()
    {
        enemyNPC1.Image = Properties.Resources.Zombie;
        enemyNPC2.Image = Properties.Resources.Zombie;
        enemyNPC3.Image = Properties.Resources.Skeleton;
        enemyNPC4.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieFlip;
        enemyNPC5.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieFlip;
        enemyNPC6.Image = Properties.Resources.SkeletonFlip;
    }

    private void EnemiesGo()
    {

    }

    private void SpriteAttack()
    {
        if (spritePC.Image == Properties.Resources.KnightIdle)
        {
            SpriteSwingRight();
        }
        else
        {
            SpriteSwingLeft();
        }

        AttackTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void SpriteSwingRight()
    {
        spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightSwing;
    }

    private void SpriteSwingLeft()
    {
        spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightSwingFlip;
    }

    private void SpriteTurnRight()
    {
        spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightIdle;
    }

    private void SpriteTurnLeft()
    {
        spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightIdleFlip;
    }


    private void SpriteShield()
    {

    }

    private void SpriteDeath()
    {

    }

    private void startLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Intro;
        titleLabel.Hide();
        startLabel.Hide();
        introLabel.Show();
    }

    private void introLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Land;
        introLabel.Hide();
        spritePC.Show();
        EnemiesReady();

    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            SpriteTurnRight();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            SpriteTurnLeft();
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            // i dunno he swings his soouurd or something
            SpriteAttack();
        }
    }

    private void AttackTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AttackTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(AttackTimer_Tick);

        AttackTimer.Start();
        if (spritePC.Image == Properties.Resources.KnightSwing)
        {
            spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightIdle;
        }
        else
        {
            spritePC.Image = Properties.Resources.KnightIdleFlip;
        }

        AttackTimer.Stop();
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Going beyong roo's answer: I highly recommend to create a class to hold not just an image but also information about it. imagecomaprisons are always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (spritePC.Image == Properties.Resources.KnightIdle)
```

You cannot compare images like this. Because when you call `Properties.Resources...` you will always get new instance of the images. However you can keep a local copy of those images to be able to compare them. Put these fields on the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap _KnightSwingFlip = Properties.Resources.KnightSwingFlip;
    Bitmap _KnightSwing = Properties.Resources.KnightSwing;
    Bitmap _KnightIdle = Properties.Resources.KnightIdle;
    // rest of code
}
```

and then use them everywhere on the form

```
public Form1()
{
     // rest of code
     spritePC.Image = _KnightIdle;
}
```

and

```
private void SpriteAttack()
{
    if (spritePC.Image == _KnightIdle)
    // rest of the code here
}
```

please keep in mind that you should change rest of your code accordingly. i.e Wherever you are using `Properties.Resources...` use the local copy instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this.

Comment: @StephenFleece if this worked for you plz accept the answer